# pygame - Making one sprite move with the mouse and another sprite move with the keyboard?

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to get the each sprite to move independently onscreen. First part is mostly filler/defining variables, I've highlighted the problem a little lower down.

The one being controlled by the keyboard is working, but the sprite I am trying to control with the mouse stands still is standing still. Might be a variable issue but I can't seem to figure out exactly what it is. Wondering how I can fix this?

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import time

pygame.init()

#preset colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

#screen display
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)) 
pygame.display.set_caption("RADICAL")
screen.fill(white)

#sprites and sounds
imga = pygame.image.load('coina.png')
imgb = pygame.image.load('coinb.png')

imgc = pygame.image.load('berrya.png')
imgd = pygame.image.load('berryb.png')
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('coin.wav')

#preset variables
FPS = 30
imgx = 10
imgy = 10
picx = 1
picy = 1
pixMove = 5
steps = 0  
x1 = 0 
y1 = 0
stepsb = 0
x2 = 0  
y2 = 0
fpsTime = pygame.time.Clock()

#actions
GameOver = False
while not GameOver:
    screen.fill(white)
    imgx += x1
    imgy += y1

    picx += x2
    picy += y2

    points = (steps)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
    text = font.render('Control the coin with the keyboard, and the berry   with the mouse', True, black)
    screen.blit(text, (0,0))

    if steps % 2 == 0: 
        screen.blit(imga, (imgx, imgy))
    else:
        screen.blit(imgb, (imgx, imgy))

    if stepsb % 2 == 0: 
        screen.blit(imgc, (picx, picy))
    else:
        screen.blit(imgd, (picx, picy))        

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

This is the specific portion of code I am having issues with

```
        elif event == MOUSEMOTION:
            (x2, y2) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Everything after this is working, or at least I think so.

```
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                y1 -= pixMove
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                y1 += pixMove
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                x1 -= pixMove
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                x1 += pixMove
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x1 = 0 
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x1 = 0 
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y1 = 0 
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y1 = 0
                steps +=1

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsTime.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic isn't quite right. The keyboard sprite is moving pixMove at a time, while the mouse sprite is moving most of a screen; get_pos() will return the current position of the mouse, so it will very quickly fly off the screen.

Your current problem is "event == MOUSEMOTION" instead of "event.type == MOUSEMOTION".